# Getting Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have problem when i want get the picture of rockpaperscissors, i want the output's same like the picture. I try to get the matrix, like [1,0,0] for paper, [0,1,0] for rock, and [0,0,1] for scissors, but in the end of the code, it give an error.

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimage
%matplotlib inline

uploaded = files.upload()
for i in uploaded.keys():
  path = i
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size = (150,150))
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size = 24)
  print(i)
  print(classes)
  if classes == [1,0,0]:
    print('paper')
  elif classes == [0,1,0]:
    print('rock')
  else:
    print('scissors')
```

and the error's

```
Saving 1i1dlQrE6JnhYXE4.png to 1i1dlQrE6JnhYXE4 (1).png
1i1dlQrE6JnhYXE4.png
[[0. 0. 1.]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-424-20a0d9bb67f4> in <module>()
     18   print(i)
     19   print(classes)
---> 20   if classes == [1,0,0]:
     21     print('paper')
     22   elif classes == [0,1,0]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

how can i fix the code? and the result's paper = paper, rock = rock, and scissors = scissors

Comment: Since it is apparent that your results are in the form `[[0. 0. 1.]]`, try `if classes == [[1., 0., 0]]` (double brackets and floats).

Comment: Yes, try double brackets and also you can just use `random.choice(('rock','paper','scissors'))`

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be using-

```py
classes == [[1., 0., 0.]]
```

But this would not work always, in fact, it would work in very limited cases only. So, what you could instead do is use this piece of code which extracts the maximum value from the list-

```py
max_index = classes[0].index(max(classes[0]))
```

And then compare the `max_index` like this-

```py
if max_index == 0:
  print("rock")
elif max_index == 1:
  print("paper")
else:
  print("scissor")
```

Also note that this is a very small sample space so I hardcoded `print()` however you would ideally want to have a lookup table and you could easily do that too.

Comment: it can't mister, it'll have a error like this "" ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() "" .

Comment: max_index = classes[0].index(max(classes[0]))

if max_index == 0:
  print("rock")
elif max_index == 1:
  print("paper")
else:
  print("scissor")

I already using this before, but just classes_index_paper = classes[0] . It gave the same error with your code, I dont know how to solve this hahah it makes me stress, i do the same to ask with my senior, but him can't helped

Comment: I used the same code which I wrote above and here's a screenshot showing it works for me- https://imgur.com/zsQo0o9

Comment: i can't open your photo, cause my nation has block it. can you give me your email? much question i want discuss with you sir

Answer (score 0):

I have done to solved it, i make the list from the rock paper scissor array, which's like this [1., 0. , 0.] etc , from that array i using statement list to change that array to be list, and then calling the list to give output .